# Accessing an Undefined External Array

Tags: c, arrays, undefined

I'm working through K&R so pardon my mediocre understanding of C. I'm trying to store the values of argv as ints in an external array. So my first question is: is it possible to create an external array with size dependent on argc? Or is there any workaround other than just using an arbitrarily long array and hoping it all fits.

Second I was experimenting with using a pointer to an undefined integer array. I was able to increment the pointer a large number of times, both reading from (almost everything was zero) and writing to the pointed memory before I got a "Bus error: 10." Is there a reason that I was able to access so much memory before I got a bus error, or is that all just part of "undefined behavior?"

Here is the code that tested the undefined array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void);
int test();

int a[];

int main(void)
{
    test();
}

int test()
{
    extern int a[];

    int *a0 = a;
    printf("%d\n", *a0);
    while (1) {
        *a0 = 1;
        a0++;
        printf("%d\n", *a0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *So my first question is: is it possible to create an external array with size dependent on argc?* I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Read on! `malloc` was already invented in K&R. However, you should use a more recent book which covers C99 at least. No new code will be written in K&R-C and you might acquire quite some bad habits from K&R-C. Note that `extern` has a very different meaning. You also seem not to have understood some concepts correctly and a different book might have different didactics and viewpoints.

Comment: Indeed, @Olaf. K&R at least has a reputation for successfully teaching generations of people C. I fear that this person is using a different resource along the side, perhaps one not so reputable and likely even more inaccurate. Where else would he get the idea to use `extern` from?

Comment: **Important note: The point of the exercise is to test your understanding of the chapter preceding it. Is it possible that you're missing the point of the exercise? Complete the exercise as it was intended to be completed, then move on. Once you've finished the book, experiment to your heart's content.**

Comment: Nobody mentioned this yet, but `int a[];` is a *tentative definition* equivalent to `int a[1];` .   `extern int a[];` is redundant because `a` is already extern and visible.  The first iteration of the `while` loop is OK and the second one writes out of bounds.

Comment: @Seb: I also started to learn C from the original K&R. With a Pascal background back then, I soon decided to throw the book into a corner and went happily with 68000 Assembler (sic!) and Modula-2 instead. Took ~10 years until I tried again - with C90. Sorry, but I do not think this is a good resource to learn **modern** C. And ancient C should not be learned by anyone anymore.

Comment: @M.M: `int a[]` is an incomplete type and not equivalent to `int a[1]`. And the `extern` part is clearly due to missconception of OP about the meaning of the specifier.

Comment: @Olaf I mean that in OP's code it is equivalent to that, since he never does `sizeof a`. . See C11 6.9.2/2 for a full description.

Comment: The tentative definition is not related to the VLA being an incomplete type (it is not just about `sizeof`). Anyway, this helps no one; OP apparently has a completely wrong understanding about the purpose of `extern` and other concepts.

Comment: @Olaf Until you can name a C99 (or better yet, C11) resource that can establish the same reputation as K&R, you're complaining without a solution in sight. If you think you can do better, do try! I look forward to criticising (constructively, of course) your attempt at teaching. Obviously, the first edition of K&R is about as useful as a two hundred year old dictionary. The second edition teaches C89, which is not extremely incompatible with C99 or C11; the changes can be explained from there.

Comment: @Seb: Not being a supreme chef does not mean I cannot tell a good from a bad menu. And it certainly does not disallow me to criticise. There have been quite some practices established and the focus has shifted since the last release of K&R. For instance, threads were not a subject. And for "not extreme incompatible": it's the small incompatibilities which are often the problem. A single one is already sufficient, if it is used in a project. Nobody should start with pre-C99 anymore. But he should be made aware about its differences. So: get the stones - "Jehova, Jehova" (<crazy dancing>).

Comment: @Olaf **What are you proposing as an alternative?** You haven't told us anything *better*. You seem to be dancing around preaching to the stars with a book that doesn't yet exist, or that you can't even name. Do you recall how highly I wrote of K&R? To recap, **I didn't**. I'm happy to critique something, and if I think it's better, I too will start recommending it. The thing about C is it isn't so subjective as cooking; there are more rigid rules in C that must not be broken, and while K&R does teach a slightly broken set of rules that's a lot easier to repair than most. Furthermore...

Comment: @Olaf The problem with most books is they aren't written with the experience of a teacher. Try to keep this in mind when you're choosing an alternative to K&R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to create an external array with size dependent on `argc`?

Not really. You can allocate an array and store a pointer to it into a global storage segment, but it would be a pointer, not an array.

> I was able to increment the pointer a large number of times, both reading from (almost everything was zero) and writing to the pointed memory before I got a "Bus error: 10."

The very first read or write outside the array is illegal. The fact that you do not get "Buss Error: 10." right away is an unfortunate coincidence, because the code may appear to work when it is actually incorrect.

> is that all just part of "undefined behavior?"

Yes, this is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's clarify a bit what extern does. In C, there's a thing called translation units. For now, imagine them as being just .c files. When you compile them, each .c file forms a translation unit and produces an object file (.o). The object files are then put together to create the final executable file by the linker. Sometimes you want to define (i.e. "create") something, like an array, in one translation unit, but use it in multiple translation units. This is fine as long as C is concerned: everything MUST be defined ONCE, but can be used multiple times. However, you need to inform the compiler that you want the array defined in another translation unit, not to define another array. In order to do this, you use the extern keyword.

In your case, your array a is just a global array, that can be accessed from anywhere in this translation unit (i.e. in this file). So, you don't really need to declare it in the main function using the extern keyword.

What you really want to ask is whether you can create a global array with a size equal to argc.

Up until C99 (K&R is pre-C99), the size of the array must be constant. So you have to create an array big enough. However, you should not hope that it fits - this is a very common way to create bugs and vulnerabilities. Instead, you should check if its usage is sensible and if the size is exceeded, generate an error. If you don't, you get undefined behaviour. It may work, or it may not. And it may be exploited for malicious purposes.

The C99 standard suports variable length arrays, so you can have something like int a[argc];. However, this works just for a local array.

The solution would be to create a global pointer and allocate dinamically memory for it in the main function using the malloc function.

Comment: Thank you. Dasblinkenlight was more to the point in answering most of my questions, but you provided a lot of helpful information as well. Would upvote if I could.

Comment: Note that C11 made VLAs optional (I do not support this decission). There is also no way to find out if the array was successfully allocated or leads to exhausting the `auto` variable space (likely a stack).